# How can I update my Samsung Galaxy Gio without a PC/Kies?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-gio

I have a Samsung Galaxy Gio and at home we do not have a computer. Is there anyway I can update or upgrade my software without using a computer? It will be fine if I have to download a few apps for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. There is an official 2.3.6 upgrade available, but it's not available using Android's over-the-air (OTA) update system, so you have to use Samsung Kies on a PC to flash it to the phone. There are also unofficial 4.1.2 upgrades available, but similarly, you need Kies to flash the phone.